# Renaming dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a Pandas dataframe where the column indices are tuples of size 3. I noticed some of them are only of size 2 and have missed a value. I have been trying to rename those columns by doing so:

```
    for x in df.columns:
        if len(x) == 2:
            y = list(x)
            y.insert(1, 'missing_str')
            df.rename(columns={x, tuple(y)}, inplace=True)
```

However, I got a TypeError: 'set' object is not callable.

Would appreciate any help to solve with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.rename(columns=...)` requires a dict or a function. You are providing a set. Did you mean `{x: tuple(y)}`?